# Firebase Integration Sample for iOS (FriendlyPix)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I’m using Googles sample app, running from their workspace file, to see how specifically Firebase Authentication works.  I downloaded their sample project, installed the CocoaPods via terminal, and have ran Pod Update to ensure everything is up to date.

When I compile everything goes smooth until the very end with a single compiler crash for “No Such Module” for “import FirebaseAuthUI”.

I can post the code when I get home, and feel there may be something wrong with the header search path in build settings, have tried adding $(SCROOT) and continues to have an issue finding the frameworks.

I’ve scoured the net and have seen other issues finding Firebase pods just like this, just wondering what could be wrong.  Here is a link to the project, I have not modified this project at all.  Just wanted to see it work.

https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-ios

Comment: I definitely would never, ever use cocoapods for this.  Use ordinary Carthage in iOS when installing the main Firebase libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FirebaseAuthUI` & `FirebaseGoogleAuthUI` are now part of `FirebaseUI`.

So you should replace all the `import FirebaseAuthUI` & `import FirebaseGoogleAuthUI` with **`import FirebaseUI`**

You will be ready to go.